# How to receive a notification when someone edits my project's GitHub wiki

Tags: github, notifications, wiki

I own a GitHub organisation and project. Unknown people (out of the organization) sometimes edit my project's wiki, which is cool.

How can I receive a notification when someone edits my project's GitHub wiki?
I "watch" my project but don't receive any notification.

Preferably via email or RSS/Atom.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that you only have to have the project watched. It should send you notifications when anything such as issues and the WIKI are updated.

UPDATE:

As the updated question states, watching does not give you updates on the Wiki.

However, this question has been asked on StackOverflow: [How can you track or be notified of changes to GitHub wikis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407917/how-can-you-track-or-be-notified-of-changes-to-github-wikis) A couple of approaches are given including an RSS feed & one based on [Service Hooks](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/).

The RSS feed is easy to use. The URL is not exposed anywhere but is built up like this:

```
https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/wiki.atom
```

Comment: I am watching the project already :-/ I edited my question to add this information.

Comment: I probably should have realised that anyway. Please see my update.

Comment: That StackOverflow had come up in my previous web searches. It asks for *service hooks*, which excludes simpler solutions. There must be something easier than using service hooks.

Comment: Is there a problem using the RSS feed?

Comment: Nice find! Unfortunately https://github.com/aegif/CmisSync/wiki.atom does not seem to be a valid feed, it breaks my RSS feed reader and does not validate: https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Faegif%2FCmisSync%2Fwiki.atom I sent a bug report to Github about that.

Comment: I checked one of mine at it is [OK](https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FTotallyInformation%2Fnoderunner%2Fwiki), did you actually create any pages yet? The feed doesn't exist until you create at least on page

Comment: Yes, the wiki has many pages already: https://github.com/aegif/CmisSync/wiki/

Comment: Looks like the w3c validator is brain-dead! I used the feed in Firefox and Feedly and both were happy with it. The validator dislikes the embedded content for some reason though it looks perfectly valid to me. You might try running it through Yahoo Pipes! if your reader doesn't like it.

Comment: Reply from Github support: "*Thanks for the heads up! The feed comes up ok in Firefox but there does look like an error based on the validator check (thanks for that link!). Though I can't make any promises about if or when this might get resolved, we'll go ahead and open an issue for our engineers to take a look.*"

Comment: Well that is in line with my own comment. The fault really lies with the validator as far as I can see as the feed looks valid to me. If it is failing in a reader, I'd raise it with the dev.